# Element with two classes under className

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, css-modules

I can not seem to find this answer anywhere! Basically I am using CSS Modules, and I am importing the file. Here is an example of the CSS file:

```
.class1 {
  ...
}
.class2 {
  ...
}
```

And then here is what I have so far in my JS file:

```
import styles from './header.scss';
export const Header = () => (
  <div className={styles.class1}>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

I am not sure how to add two classes to `className`, the following does not work:

```
import styles from './header.scss';
export const Header = () => (
  <div className={styles.class1, styles.class2}>
    ...
  </div>
);
```

Please help, how do I achieve putting two classes on to one element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The styles are just strings, so you can use templates or string concatenation:

```
<div className={ `${styles.class1} ${styles.class2}` }>
```

or

```
<div className={ styles.class1 + ' ' + styles.class2 }>
```

or

```
<div className={ [styles.class1, styles.class2].join(' ') }>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe it's that simple! In the first example you gave, what is the ` for?

Comment: ES6 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: My downvote happened by accident - but I can't remove it now.  If you edit your post, I'll remove the downvote.